# PHP: Trying to figure out how to extract words from a string

Tags: php

I would like to create an array of all the words in a string.  I tried to Google but only found `str_split`, which does not separate the words.

Comment: could you be more specific and show us some example!

Comment: you can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your words are separated with several spaces, tabs or new lines, you may want to ignore them.

```
$string  = "    a   bunch    of  words   ";
$string = trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $string));
$array_of_words = explode(" ", $string);
```

Gives:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "bunch"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "of"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "words"
}
```

Comment: You allready replaced all whitespaces through `\s` so `str_replace()`  isn't needed!

Answer (score 2):

You can typically use explode():

```
$string  = "a bunch of words";
$array_of_words = explode(" ", $string);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
$new_array = explode(' ', $your_string);
```

Now `$new_array` contains a string for every word in `$your_string`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the solution

```
$string  = "    a   bunch    of  words   ";
$array_of_words = preg_split("/\s/", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

that gives

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "bunch"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "of"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "words"
}
```

IMO is more elegant.